# Why is my HTML page's title showing up as plain text on the page?

Tags: html

The title does show up in the browser's title bar as expected, but it also shows up as text on the first line of the Web page.  Here's the HTML.  What gives?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin.css" title="" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
        <title>User pics</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http:/blah.s3.amazonaws.com/1xrfnyf08goxpsda1mhs.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I moved the stylesheet reference into the head, per Devang's suggestion.

Comment: You should update the question to contain a clear and concise formulation of the problem, not an answer. And an answer should give a clear and concise description of a solution.

Comment: It already contained a clear description of the problem.  I moved the answer into the response that inspired it.

Comment: The question still does not describe the problem. It contains a document that refers to a style sheet with a relative address, and the problem is in that style sheet. The HTML document as such is irrelevant, because the CSS code is the issue.

Comment: The question describes the problem, as does the title. You're talking about the solution. There's nothing more to say about the problem.

Comment: back then, the OP probably was thinking in terms of "im the only person that's ever gonna read this", the commenters were talking in terms of "what happens when someone else comes along and sees this, it wont make sense"   I stumbled in here and was confused, had to read the comments to find out what the heck was going on with the question. FWICT, the question looks like its changed to the answer.

Comment: Nope. Read the comment right above yours. This post hasn't changed in years. What are you "confused" about? I don't see how the question could be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove css reference and check it once.. may be the issue with css

Comment: How is this an answer? An approved answer? It should have been a comment.

Comment: It's an answer because nobody else provided one, and providing my own simply saying "it was the CSS" would be unfair to Madhabendra. I moved my description of the full solution into it.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User pics</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin.css" title="" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http:/blah.s3.amazonaws.com/1xrfnyf08goxpsda1mhs.jpg" alt="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**You can not define link tag outside html tag.**

Comment: Thanks.  Although your suggestion is correct as far as where to put the stylesheet reference, it doesn't change the output at all (and I verified the source to be sure it wasn't cached).

Comment: blah.s3.amazonaws.com/1xrfnyf08goxpsda1mhs.jpg , have you tried accessing it ?

Comment: Yes, the image shows up fine (I changed the URL for this example).

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
*{
    display:block; 
}
```

in your CSS file make sure to remove it because that will cause the title to show up

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly close the link tag above. 
You have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="admin.css" title="" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
```

it should read

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="admin.css" title="" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>
```